# How to get Facebook Friends count in Facebook Php sdk v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK v 5.0 and I am trying to get Facebook friends.
I am using the following code:

```
$requestFriends = $fb->request('GET', '/me/friends?fields=id,name');
$batchFrineds = ['user-friends' => $requestFriends,];

$responsesFriends = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batchFrineds);

  foreach ($responsesFriends as $key => $response) 
  {
    //echo "Response: " . var_dump($response) . "</p>\n\n";
  }
```

And the result is here:

```
[
{
    "code":200,
    "headers":[{"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value":"*"},
    {"name":"ETag","value":"\"2339ed6ac11ca077990150e70a0b2b00c80710e9\""},
    {"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},
    {"name":"Pragma","value":"no-cache"},
    {"name":"Cache-Control","value":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"},
    {"name":"Content-Type","value":"text\/javascript; charset=UTF-8"},
    {"name":"Facebook-API-Version","value":"v2.0"},
    {"name":"Expires","value":"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"}],
    "body":
        "{
            \"data\":
            [
                {\"id\":\"100001258423346\",\"name\":\"\\u0414. \\u0410\\u043d\\u0430\\u0440\"},{\"id\":\"100001340034751\",\"name\":\"Jani BoLd\"},{\"id\":\"100001689146477\",\"name\":\"\\u0411. \\u041d\\u044f\\u043c\\u0441\\u04af\\u0440\\u044d\\u043d\"},{\"id\":\"100001734957601\",\"name\":\"\\u041d\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430\\u0430 \\u04e8\\u043b\\u0437\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u0430\\u0439\\u0445\\u0430\\u043d\"},{\"id\":\"100002982584139\",\"name\":\"\\u0411. \\u041d\\u044f\\u043c\\u0441\\u04af\\u0440\\u044d\\u043d\"},{\"id\":\"100003030795256\",\"name\":\"\\u0425\\u0438\\u0448\\u0433\\u044d\\u044d \\u0418\\u0440\\u043c\\u04af\\u04af\\u043d\"},{\"id\":\"100003970992671\",\"name\":\"\\u0411\\u0430\\u0442 \\u041e\\u0440\\u0448\\u0438\\u0445\"},{\"id\":\"100005014861144\",\"name\":\"\\u0411. \\u0410\\u0431\\u0443\\u0443\"},{\"id\":\"100005092027529\",\"name\":\"Oyun Nyamaa\"}
            ],
            \"paging\":
                {\"next\":\"https:\\\/\\\/graph.facebook.com\\\/v2.0\\\/1635590113348375\\\/friends?fields=id,name&access_token=9cGq\"
                },
            \"summary\":
                    {
                        \"total_count\":406
                    }
        }"
}
 ]
```

But I can't get friends total count on that result.

Comment: The value is there, in the data you have shown. So what exactly is your problem – how to access it? Well it looks like you are making this harder on yourself as it would need to be, by making a batch request. Make a normal request instead, then you get a JSON data structure containing only the data right away.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `summary` with a `total_count` in the response (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends#readfields)).